# Is it possible to have a local user with the same name as a domain user

Tags: active-directory

I have a linux box set up with a local user that I've been using. If I join this computer to a domain using realm, will there be a conflict if the AD user I will be logging into has the same username as the local user?

Answer (score 4):

If you are using `sssd` to authenticate with your AD, then users are created with a domain in the name by default.  This is controlled by `default_domain_suffix` in [`sssd.conf`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/sssd.conf).

Normally, I would add my domain to that option.  This means if I log in as `john`, with `default_domain_suffix=example.com`, then it will authenticate as `john@example.com`.  This is obviously a conflict if you also have a local user `john`.

In your case, I suggest deleting this option (which I think is default).  You'll be able to choose to login as `john` (local user) or `john@example.com` (domain user)